# Erro no Módulo config do NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm

Tenho um arquivo mysql.js que efetua o acesso ao banco conforme abaixo:

```
'use strict';
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    config = require('config');  
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.get('mysql.server'),
    user: config.get('mysql.username'),
    password: config.get('mysql.password'),
    database: config.get('mysql.database'),
    port: config.get('mysql.port')
});
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});
module.exports = connection;
```

Estou usando o módulo config (config.get(mysql.server), por exemplo) para buscar os dados de acesso ao banco de dados de acordo com o modelo abaixo (default.json) localizado na raiz da aplicação dentro de uma pasta chamada config:

```
{
  "mysql": {
    "database": "BANCODEDADOS",
    "password": "SENHA",
    "port": "PORTA",
    "server": "SERVIDOR",
    "username": "USUARIO"
  }
}
```

Estou usando o Visual Studio para trabalha nesse projeto.

O que está acontecendo...

Quando eu pressiono F5 dentro do vscode, funciona normalmente acessando o banco e os demais recurso. Sem problemas!

Quando eu vou dar um restart dentro do vscode (Ctrl + Shit + F5), da um erro na conexão informando que não foi possível encontrar as informações no arquivo default.json(arquivo aonde tenho as credenciais de acesso conforme print acima.(config.get(mysql.server) é undefined, por exemplo) e ai, o módulo config me retorna um erro undefined:

```
node --debug-brk=21502 --nolazy www 
Debugger listening on [::]:21502
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:c:\Users\claudio.campos\Documents\Arquivos\Outros\Estudos\Projetos\Site\Aplicacao\bin\config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
c:\Users\claudio.campos\Documents\Arquivos\Outros\Estudos\Projetos\Site\Aplicacao\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:181
    throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
    ^

Error: Configuration property "mysql.server" is not defined
    at Config.get (c:\Users\claudio.campos\Documents\Arquivos\Outros\Estudos\Projetos\Site\Aplicacao\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:181:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\claudio.campos\Documents\Arquivos\Outros\Estudos\Projetos\Site\Aplicacao\db\mysql.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\claudio.campos\Documents\Arquivos\Outros\Estudos\Projetos\Site\Aplicacao\routes\categoria.js:5:13)
```

Alguem sabe me dizer o porque isso só acontece quando eu dou um restart no vscode?

Comment: Coloca aqui código e não imagens pf. Quando dizes `F5` referes-te ao browser? ou estás a reiniciar o servidor?

Comment: Editei a pergunta!
F5 se refere ao vscode, só que por exemplo, estou com o debug no código, só que eu quero dar um restart no vscode... teoricamente reincia o servidor sim.
Tudo isso acontece só de dar um restart.